# Div bars behind picture in normal and mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website where I have a picture of a person. Right to the picture I want to have the name and a description. The name should have a different background than the description. 
I uploaded a picture of how it should look like: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=fa13202
And here is what I came up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/dse74/

```
#empty {
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#rightRed {
    padding-left:220px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    height:40px;
}
#right {
    padding-left:220px;
    position:absolut;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    z-index: 2;
}

<div>
    <div id="left">
        <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20071127032702/uncyclopedia/images/1/16/641px-Mad_scientist_transparent_background.svg.png" style="width:180px" />
    </div>
    <div id="empty"></div>
    <div id="rightRed">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu ullamcorper risus, id varius eros. Nullam eleifend augue convallis, consectetur elit non, condimentum diam. Nullam sapien nibh, congue hendrerit placerat at, convallis scelerisque nisl. Morbi viverra tortor nisi, tincidunt ornare dui consequat id. Aliquam lorem tellus, egestas et nunc a, faucibus ullamcorper nunc. Sed sollicitudin sapien eget tellus faucibus, quis semper dolor vehicula. In placerat nulla mi, sit amet luctus tellus placerat sed.t</div>
</div>
```

It looks ok for normal browsers, but unfortunately in mobile browsers it doesn't look like how I want it. Here is a picture what I want to achieve for mobile browsers: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=10ac016

Unfortunately I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` in the head and add `@media only screen and (max-width:640px)` to your css like this:

```
#empty {
            width: 100%;
            height:40px;
        }
        #left {
            float:left;
            width:180px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #rightRed {
            padding-left:220px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:red;
            height:40px;
        }
        #right {
            padding-left:220px;
            background-color:#00FF00;
            z-index: 2;
        }
    @media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
        #rightRed {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0px;   
        }
        #right {
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 0px;
        }
    }
```

If the screensize is 640px or less it will align the text to the center and remove the padding.
http://jsfiddle.net/UuP9Y/